# Creating an object from transformable core data on iOS using NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, core-data

I am using core data to retrieve a transferrable object which is then saved as an NSArray as follows:

```
NSArray *bigDataResultsArray = [XAppDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:bigDataFetchRequest error:&error];
NSArray *bigDataResultsArrayJSON = [bigDataResultsArray valueForKey:@"bigData"];
```

I am able to get valueForKey down to a smaller object array however it is only appearing as 1 object.

When I try to extract "Value" from the following I get the error that it is non value compliant. The data is in the following format and will not parse to JSON:

I try to extract value using the following:

```
    NSArray *styleArray = [bigDataResultsArrayJSON valueForKey:@"Styles"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [styleArray valueForKey:@"Value"]);
```

Which gives an error. However if i log the style array I get the following"

```
(
            {
        Total = 1;
        Value = 5;
    },
            {
        Total = 1;
        Value = "5.5";
    },
            {
        Total = 75;
        Value = 6;
    },
            {
        Total = 4;
        Value = "6.5";
    },
            {
        Total = 239;
        Value = 7;
    },
            {
        Total = 149;
        Value = "7.5";
    },
            {
        Total = 260;
        Value = 8;
    },
            {
        Total = 214;
        Value = "8.5";
    },
            {
        Total = 259;
        Value = 9;
    },
            {
        Total = 196;
        Value = "9.5";
    },
            {
        Total = 254;
        Value = 10;
    },
            {
        Total = 148;
        Value = "10.5";
    },
            {
        Total = 237;
        Value = 11;
    },
            {
        Total = 38;
        Value = 12;
    },
            {
        Total = 2;
        Value = 13;
    }
)
)
```

Can anyone assist me with extracting the final layer of this data into an array of value objects. I have tried converting to NSData then to JSON as follows but the format of the data will not parse:

```
NSData *raw = [[ra valueForKey:@"bigData"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? You want to store an array in a managed object without creating a new entity and setting a new relationship?

Comment: *"When I try to extract "Value" ..."* - What exactly did you try? - *"... and will not parse to JSON"* - Did you have a look at NSJSONSerialization?

Comment: Hi I have updated my answer. I am trying to get an array of the Value items from a far bigger data object. I have looked as NSJSONSerialization but get an error when passing the array/str/data to the encoder. thanks in advance

Comment: @EHarpham: What is `coloursArray`? It is not defined in your code. (You *did* copy/paste the real code, didn't you?) - And please show what you tried with NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: Apologies. coloursArray was supposed to be stylesArray. Have edited code.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract an array with just one field from an array of dictionaries:

```
NSArray *dictArray = @[{@"total" : @1, @"value" : @5},
  {@"Total" : @1, @"Value" : @5.5}, … ];
NSArray *resultsArray = [dictArray valueForKeyPath:@"value"];

---> @[@5, @5.5, …];
```

You can do the same with an array of core data objects:

```
// ... create the managed objects and fill their attributes
object.total = @1;
object.value = @5; 
// etc
NSArray *resultsArray = [fetchedObjects valueForKeyPath:@"value"];

---> @[@5, @5.5, …];
```

Comment: thanks for this. If i do not know how large the dictArray will be how would I create this?

Comment: Use `NSMutableArray` and call `addObject` in a loop.

Comment: the object i retrieve from core data is only showing as 1 object so unsure how I can do this. This was my original problem

Answer (score 0):

Your styleArray is an array of dictionaries. Arrays do not have key-value pairs; each element of the array does. What Mundi is saying is the correct answer, and will give you a single array of values.

To be super explicit, you can loop through the elements of styleArray, and extract each dictionary individually, and maybe this will be more clear to you.

```
NSArray *styleArray = [bigDataResultsArrayJSON valueForKey:@"Styles"];

NSMutableArray *valuesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0; i<styleArray.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *styleDictionary = styleArray[i];
    id valueObj = [styleDictionary objectForKey:@"Value"];
    [valuesArray addObject:valueObj];
}

NSLog(@"Values: %@", valuesArray);
```